# How to create 4-bit asynchronous counter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, clock, timer, flipflop, counter

I am new to Multimedia Logic and am trying to create a 4-bit asynchronous counter. I did something like this, but it doesn't work.

I'm not sure if everything is properly connected and if I was using a good clock or flip-flops.

I was expecting that first light will flash on and off every second and last every eight seconds but nothing happens.

[image: my circuit]

Comment: Please try to provide a more detailed description than *"it doesn't work"*. What were you expecting and what was the behavior?

Comment: @devnull i was expecting that first ligh will flash on and off every second and last every eight second but nothing happens.

Comment: What happens if you connect the LED to the clock input of the first FF? It it doesn't blink you have to check how to enable the clock pulses in the simulator. The JK FFs with both inputs 1 will swap its output state at every clock (at the edge it senses).

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Multimedia, now that's a term I haven't heard since the nineties! What makes this one multimedia?

Comment: @winny It is indeed a interesting name for a simulator: https://sourceforge.net/projects/multimedialogic/ (abandoned, it seems).

Comment: @winny It looks like a nineties program!

Comment: Is there maybe some button you have to press to make the simulation start? I see in the toolbar there is a green arrow, like a play button.

Comment: does the 0 output of the clock go on every second, or just every 8 seconds? It looks like wires turn green when they are on, does anything turn green?

Comment: @user253751 Great find! Does it requires a 2x CD and SoundBlaster 16 or compatible to run? :-)

Comment: @devnull i connected clock to LED and it blinks every 2 seconds

Comment: Then it would be interesting if you could try another simulator. It is strange to see the connected wires without bullets and bullets in places where there are no wires with T connections. We don't even know if the circuit is properly connected.

Comment: @devnull ok i will try to do something, thanks mate

Comment: Gross. Don’t like the wire junction symbols at the pins. Unnecessary clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a supplied circuit. From [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip).

And it is an animated circuit if you want.

[image]